# Is there a way to export a blob column in teradata to a CSV file via a bteq script?

Tags: teradata

I have the following shell script that has a bteq call to export a Teradata BLOB field to a text file. I discovered if the file is > 64K it does not get written. I know I can set the INDICDATA DEFERLIMITS=0,0 and then it will write the name of the BLOB file it creates in the filename I supplied. The filename I supply contains a path and that file is being written in the correct location. The BLOB file that is being created I cannot find on the server. I thought it would be created in the same directory but I don't see it. Do I have to set that location also? If so, how?

```
-------------------------------
Shell Script with BTEQ:
-----------------------------------
#!/bin/sh
modelId=$1
runId=$2
filename=$3
file1="/export/home/pc8admin/pc8store/infa_shared/bin/ENGV_D042A/${filename}"

echo $modelId
echo $runId
echo $filename 
echo $file1

bteq  <<lbl_btq


.RUN FILE=/export/home/pc8admin/pc8store/infa_shared/OAS/td_mlbtq_engv_etl.scr

.EXPORT INDICDATA FILE = $file1;

.SET LARGEDATAMODE ON;
.EXPORT LDOPREFIX 'doc_'
.EXPORT LDOSUFFIX 'txt' 

DATABASE XXX_XX;
.IF errorlevel <> 0 THEN .QUIT errorcode;

SELECT  IL.FIL_OBJ_UD
FROM    XXX_XX.SIMLTR_CFG_INV_LOAD IL
INNER JOIN XXX_XX.SIMLTR_CFG_INV_LOAD_STAT ST ON IL.FIL_ID = ST.FIL_ID
WHERE ST.MDL_ID = $modelId AND ST.SIMLTR_RUN_ID = $runId AND ST.INV_TYP_ID = 'E'
AND IL.FIL_ID = 5;

.IF errorlevel <> 0 THEN .QUIT errorcode;

.END EXPORT 
.LOGOFF
.EXIT 0

lbl_btq
```

The filename I supplied contains the text: doc_FIL_OBJ_UD_r1.txt

I can't find the doc_FIL_OBJ_UD_r1.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDOPREFIX can include a relative or absolute path in addition to some filename prefix characters. If no path is included, the current working directory when BTEQ is invoked will be the assumed location.